# C++ Pointer to member of member

Tags: c++, member-pointers

```
//#define NOT_WORKS
#define HOW(X) 0

struct A {

};

struct B {
    A a;
};

struct C {
    B b;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    A B::*ba = &B::a;       // ba is a pointer to B::a member
    B C::*cb = &C::b;       // cb is a pointer to C::b member

#ifdef NOT_WORKS

    { A C::*ca = &C::b::a; }    // error: Symbol a could not be resolved / error: ‘C::b’ is not a class or namespace
    { A C::*ca = cb + ba; }     // error: invalid operands of types ‘B C::*’ and ‘A B::*’ to binary ‘operator+’

    A C::*ca = HOW(???);        // is possible to reach C::b::a by a member pointer?

#endif

    C cptr;
    A aptr = cptr.*cb.*ba;  // is pointer inference chaining the only solution?

    return 0;
}
```

If the inference chaining of member pointers is the only solution to reach a inner member, can i encapsulate this on a single type using templates?

---

Now the code can be compiled with gcc

Thank you everybody

Comment: This code look very strange and I am unable to compile it.
What mean exactly
A B::*ba = &B::a;
Are you sure that is correct?

I have see code like:
A a;
B b;
b.a=a;

And same things with pointers, but never with "::"

Comment: @AdrianMaire: `A B::*ba = &B::a;` declares `ba` to be a pointer to member of `B` of type `A` and initializes it with `&B::a`. It should compiler fine.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: thanks you, I will learn more about that.

Comment: There's no such thing as `C::b::a` in the code above. The left hand side of `::` has to be a namespace or type name. `C::b` is not either of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is possible to reach C::b::a by a member pointer?

Sort of:

```
C c; 
A B::*ca = &B::a;  //    usage: c.b.*ca;
```

> is pointer inference chaining the only solution?

Yes